# Is 'closing on mortgage loan' not equal to 'paying off all debts'?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Is 'closing on mortgage loan' not equal to 'paying off all debts'?

Here is a quote from [this article](https://sbs.arizona.edu/news/why-russians-think-americans-dont-own-their-homes):

> Russians find it odd that Americans call themselves "homeowners" from
>   the day they close on a mortgage loan. For Russians, ownership only
>   begins after all debts are paid off.

I am a bit confused here. Does 'closing on mortgage loan' not mean 'all debts are paid off'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is some financial jargon, and is principally an American usage.

"Closing" a loan is when you and the lender sign the final legal documents and the lender sends the money.  It is the last step of taking out a loan, but before you start paying back any money. https://www.readynest.com/homebuyer-stories/what-to-expect-at-loan-closing

When buying a house, this is usually done at the same time as you buy the house.  Closing the loan usually means signing lots of legal documents. After closing, you legally own the property, but the lender would have the right to take it from you if you didn't pay back the loan.

The corresponding term in British (but perhaps not Scottish) use is "Complete".

Answer (score 2):

"To close" is to finalize the purchase of a home, with the signing of documents. That phrase is used whether there is a mortgage loan or not.  The buyer becomes the owner of the home, but does not possess the deed, which is held by the mortgage company until the mortgage is paid off.
 The author seems to use the phrase "closing on a mortgage loan" to mean finalizing the purchase of a home with a mortgage. So, the phrase does not mean that all debts are paid off. And Americans who purchase a home with a mortgage are called "homeowners".